# Error when trying to convert ImageView to string

Tags: java, android

I have a ImageView that I need to create and get the bitmap of and convert to string, because I need to send the image to charquopy for procesisng.  When I attempt to get the Image as a string I get the following error below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
```

on this line specifically: `imageString = getStringImage(bitmap);`

the entire code snipped of that related to my problem:

```
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame_image);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String imageString = "";
    BitmapDrawable drawable;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    drawable = (BitmapDrawable)mImageView.getDrawable();
    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    imageString = getStringImage(bitmap); // Error occurs in this line
}
```

the frame image XML:

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frame_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/camera_view" />
```

Output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
```

I'd like to know why is it returning a null pointer given that Imageview seems to be apparently properly called.

Comment: That error message seems to indicate that the problem is on the previous line: `bitmap = drawable.getBitmap()` and that `drawable` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw the imageview on a canvas and create a bitmap out of it like this

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame_image);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageView .getWidth(), mImageView .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
mImageView.draw(canvas);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
 byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
 String imageAsString =Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
 //Upload  imageAsString
```

Comment: It needs to be converted and passed as a string though. Because then, I will call it on a python script. How can I do it using your approach?

Comment: Have updated the code,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class ImageUtil
{
    public static Bitmap convert(String base64Str) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(
            base64Str.substring(base64Str.indexOf(",")  + 1),
            Base64.DEFAULT
        );

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
    }

    public static String convert(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

        return Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

}
```